# Generating function: Solving a recursive equation

Tags: power-series, generating-functions, recursion, partial-fractions

I've got following recursive equation to solve:

$$a_n = \begin{cases} 5, & n = 0 \\ 3, & n = 1 \\ 5n^2 - 6n - 4 + a_{n-1}, & n \ge 2 \end{cases}$$

I also found the resulting generating function (I think that should be correct):

$$F(x) = z^2F(x) + \frac{5(x+1)}{(1-x)^3} - \frac{6}{(1-x)^2}  + \frac{2}{1-x} +8x + 9$$

Edit: Which of course would give me: 
$$F(x) = \left(\frac{1}{1-x^2}\right)\times \left( \frac{5(x+1)}{(1-x)^3} - \frac{6}{(1-x)^2}  + \frac{2}{1-x} +8x + 9\right)$$

How should I go forward?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

For $n\geq 1$, the solution of the linear recurrence of the first order
$$a_n -a_{n-1}=5n^2 - 6n - 4\quad\mbox{for $n \ge 2$, with $a_1=3$}$$
should have the form
$$a_n=An^3+Bn^2+Cn+D$$
where $A,B,C,D$ are constants to be determined. In fact, for $n\geq 1$,
\begin{align*}
a_n&=a_1+\sum_{k=2}^n(a_k -a_{k-1})=3+\sum_{k=2}^n (5k^2-6k-4)\\
&=
3+10\sum_{k=2}^n \binom{k}{2}-\sum_{k=2}^n k-4\sum_{k=2}^n1\\
&=3+10\binom{n+1}{3}-\binom{n+1}{2}+1-4(n-1)\\
&=\frac{5n^3}{3}-\frac{n^2}{2}-\frac{37n}{6}+8.
\end{align*}
The case $n=0$ should be considered separately:
$$a_n = \frac{5n^3}{3}-\frac{n^2}{2}-\frac{37n}{6}+
\begin{cases} 5 & n = 0 \\ 8 & n \ge 1 \end{cases}$$

Answer (score 0):

With $S_k(n)$ denoting the sum of the $k^{th}$ powers of the naturals (Faulhaber formula), the solution 
$$b_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(n^2-6n-4)=5S_2(n-1)-6S_1(n-1)-4S_0(n-1)$$

satisfies the recurrence and is such that $b_0=0,b_1=-4$.

Then by linearity, $a_n=-\dfrac12b_n+5$ satisfies all conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem contains two flaws. The first is in the text of the problem itself.

Indeed in a recurrence like yours $a_n= a_{n-1}+5n^2 - 6n - 4 \quad(*)$

the indeterminate is just one and not two. Giving both $a_0$ and $a_1$ makes the problem insolvable. So let's suppose that we know $a_0=5$.

Now suppose $F(x)=\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } a_n x^n$

multiply each term by $x^n$

$a_n x^n= a_{n-1} x^n +5n^2 x^n - 6n x^n- 4 x^n$

and add from $n=0$ to $\infty$

$\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } a_n x^n= \sum _{n=0}^{\infty } a_{n-1} x^n +5\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } n^2 x^n - 6 \sum _{n=0}^{\infty } n x^n- 4 \sum _{n=0}^{\infty } x^n$

the last series gives $-\dfrac{4}{x-1}$

$5\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } n x^n=\dfrac{5x}{(x-1)^2}$

$-6\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } n^2 x^n =\dfrac{6x (x+1)}{(x-1)^3}$

The sum is

$5\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } n^2 x^n - 6 \sum _{n=0}^{\infty } n x^n- 4 \sum _{n=0}^{\infty } x^n=\dfrac{-7 x^2-7 x+4}{(x-1)^3}$

Now comes the second flaw. Because

$\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } a_{n-1} x^n =\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } a_{n} x^{n+1}=x \sum _{n=1}^{\infty } a_{n} x^n=xF(x)$ while you wrote $x^2F(x)$

and

$\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } a_n x^n =a_0+\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } a_n x^n=5+F(x)$

therefore we have

$F(x)+5=x F(x)+\dfrac{-7 x^2-7 x+4}{(x-1)^3}$

$F(x)=\dfrac{5 x^3-8 x^2+22 x-9}{(x-1)^4}$

reduce with partial fractions

$$\frac{a}{x-1}+\frac{b}{(x-1)^2}+\frac{c}{(x-1)^3}+\frac{d}{(x-1)^4}=\dfrac{5 x^3-8 x^2+22 x-9}{(x-1)^4}$$

which gives

$$F(x)=\frac{9}{1-x}+\frac{7}{(x-1)^2}+\frac{21}{(x-1)^3}+\frac{10}{(x-1)^4}$$

and now the way back. The term of the recurrence are the MacLaurin series coefficients  of $F(x)$

$\dfrac{9}{1-x}$ gives $9 \sum _{n=0}^{\infty } x^n$ so we have $9$

$\dfrac{7}{(x-1)^2}$ gives $7 (1 + n)$

$\dfrac{21}{(x-1)^3}$ gives $-\dfrac{21}{2}(n+1) (n+2)$

and $\dfrac{10}{(x-1)^4}$ gives $\dfrac{5}{3} (n+1) (n+2) (n+3)$

The sum is $a_n=\dfrac{1}{6} \left(10 n^3-3 n^2-37 n+30\right)$

First values are $5,\; 0,\; 4,\; 27,\; 79,\; 170,\; 310,\; 509,\; 777,\; 1124,\; 1560,\;\ldots$

and we can see that $a_1\ne 3$

I have tried with $a_1=3$ but I couldn't get $a_0=5$

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You ask for a generating function. So define $A(z) = \sum_{n \ge 0} a_n z^n$, shift your recurrence (no subtraction in indices is nicer). Then multiply by $z^n$ and sum over $n \ge 0$, recognize some sums:

$\begin{align*}
   a_{n + 1}
     &= a_n + 5 n^2 + 4 n - 5 \\
   \sum_{n \ge 0} a_{n + 1} z^n
     &= \sum_{n \ge 0} a_n z^n
          + 5 \sum_{n \ge 0} n^2 z^n
          + 4 \sum_{n \ge 0} n z^n
          - 5 \sum_{n \ge 0} z^n \\
   \frac{A(z) - a_0}{z}
     &= A(z)
         + 5 \frac{z + z^2}{(1 - z)^3}
         + 4 \frac{z}{(1 - z)^2}
         - 5 \frac{1}{1 - z}
\end{align*}$

The sums at the end are the geometric sum and use of the observation:

$\begin{align*}
   \sum_{n \ge 0} n u_n z^n
     &= z  \frac{d}{d z} \sum_{n \ge 0} n u_n z^n
\end{align*}$

With the initial value this can be solved for $A(z)$:

$\begin{align*}
  A(z)
    &= \frac{5 - 20 z + 34 z^2 - 9 z^3}{(1 - z)^4}
\end{align*}$

Using the generalized binomial theorem:

$\begin{align*}
   (1 - u)^{-m}
     &= \sum_{n \ge 0} (-1)^n \binom{-m}{n} u^n \\
     &= \sum_{n \ge 0} \binom{n + m - 1}{m - 1} u^n
\end{align*}$

we get the coefficients, for $n \ge 3$:

$\begin{align*}
   [z^n] A(z)
     &= (5 [z^n] - 20 [z^{n - 1}] + 34 [z^{n - 2}] - 9 [z^{n - 3}])
           (1 - z)^{-4} \\
     &= 5 \binom{n + 4 - 1}{4 - 1}
          - 20 \binom{n - 1 + 4 - 1}{4 - 1}
          + 34 \binom{n - 2 + 4 - 1}{4 - 1}
          -  9 \binom{n - 3 + 4 - 1}{4 - 1} \\
     &= \frac{10 n^3 + 27 n^2 - 13 n}{6}
\end{align*}$

For the first values note that the coefficients of negative powers of $z$ are 0. Or ask your friendly CAS to expand $A(z)$ by Maclaurin series, or use the recurrence: $a_0 = 5, a_1 = 4, a_2 = 27, a_3 = 79, \ldots$.